# how to rename of node in extjs 4 tree

Tags: extjs, extjs4

hi friends, I am new to extjs 4 , `how to rename of extjs 4 tree node` please give me a suggestion, and give me a references.
below code of tree panel

```
var treePanel = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    id: 'tree-panel',
    title: 'Taxonomy',
    region: 'west',
    collapsible: true,
    split: true,
    //multiSelect: true,                            
    height: '100%',
    width: '20%',
    minWidth: 100,
    rootVisible: false,
    autoScroll: true,
    store: store,
    viewConfig: {
        allowCopy: true,


        plugins: {
            ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop',
            appendOnly: true,
            ddGroup: 'selDD'
        },
```

Comment: Your question is not descriptive enough.  Do you want the end user to be able to edit the node name?  Or do you need to programatically change the name of the node?

Comment: edit the node text only

Answer (score 0):

Just add a columns config and an editor to a single column, here is how I think it would work in your code:

```
var treePanel = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    id: 'tree-panel',
    title: 'Taxonomy',
    region:'west',
    collapsible: true,
    split: true,
    //multiSelect: true,                            
    height:'100%',       
    width: '20%',
    minWidth: 100,
    rootVisible: false,
    autoScroll: true,
    store: store,
    viewConfig: {
    allowCopy: true,


    plugins: {
        ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop',
        appendOnly: true,
        ddGroup:    'selDD'
    },
    columns: [
       {
           xtype:     "treecolumn",
           dataIndex: "text",
           flex:      1,
           editor:{
               xtype:      "textfield"
           }
       }
    ]
}
```